# a Standard Young Tableau symmetry and the non-attacking rook problem.

Tags: combinatorics, young-tableaux

Any standard or semi-standard Young tableau T of shape $\lambda$ of n can be transformed into an other tableau T´ of $\lambda$ by an operation flip(T) = T´. This operation 'flip' consists of the following steps:

1. extend the rows of T with zero's to obtain a rectangular array with l($\lambda$) rows 
   and $\lambda_1$ columns ;
2. reverse the row and column entries ;
3. replace each non-zero entry u by n+1-u resulting in a rectangular skew tableau
4. rectify (by jeu-de-taquin) this skew tableau to obtain the tableau T´ of $\lambda$.

Properties:

1. The operation 'flip' is an involution on the set of all SYT of $\lambda$. (proof ?)
2. The count of fixed points over all partitions of n equals:
   a(1..16) = 1, 2, 2, 6, 6, 20, 20, 76, 76, 312, 312, 1384, 1384, 6512, 6512, 32400
   (apparently equivalent to 'aerated' version of A000898 )
3. The set of counts of fixed points for the set of partitions of (2k+1) 
   seems to equal that of partitions of 2k if partitions with zero fixed points are disregarded :
   n=2 : {1, 1}
   n=3 : {1, 0, 1}
   n=4 : {1, 1, 2, 1, 1}
   n=5 : {1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1}
   n=6 : {1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 0, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1}
   n=7 : {1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 3, 3, 1, 3, 0, 2, 0, 1}
4. up to n=16, the number of fixed points for all T of shape $\lambda$ contains only prime factors 2,3,5 and 7 ;
5. The count of 2-cycles seems to equal A000900; this sequence is similarly defined as (A000085(n)-A000898(int(n/2)))/2 , but then related not to SYT symmetries but to the n-by-n non-attacking rooks problem.

Question : this must be generally known (to those who know about such things). I'm looking for a literature reference, so that I can ammend the OEIS with more than just a conjecture.

Added 2016/12/30 15:15 UTC:
Conjecture: (tested up to n=16 for SYT and n=9 for SSYT):
for both SYT and SSYT of shape $\lambda$ : # of fixed points = 0 if the 2-core of $\lambda$ differs from resp. { } (=empty) for even n or {1} for odd n ;
for  SYT of shape $\lambda$ : # of fixed points = Binomial(floor(n/2),|q1|)*h(q1)*h(q2)
for SSYT of shape $\lambda$ : # of fixed points =
for n even : c(q1,n/2)*c(q2,n/2) 
and for odd n : c(q1,(n-1)/2)*c(q2,(n+1)/2)
where h($\mu$) is the number of SYT of shape $\mu$ (hook length formula), q1 and q2 are the first and second 2-quotients of $\lambda$  and c($\mu$,k) is the count of SSYT of shape $\mu$ with largest part at most k (hook content formula).

Comment: yet an other conjecture (might help to recognise the symmetry involved): Conjecture:   
Let T1 and T2 be two SYT of $\lambda$ and fixed points of the 'flip' operation, then the RSK composition of T1 and T2 is a permutation w so that reverse(inverse(w)) = inverse(reverse(w)) aka 'double downgrading permutation'. The number of SYT that are fixed points under 'flip' equals the count of double downgrading involutions. The sum of squares of the count of fixed points over all partitions of n equals (2 floor(n/2))!!  cfr A000165.

Answer (score 1):

The operation you describe is what is called (at least by me) forming the Schützenberger dual of a standard Young tableaux (and you can carry over the definition without problem to the semi-standard case). It is not defined here in the way Schützenberger originally defined it, though he might have done something close to this in a later paper (I don't think I came up with this myself). In any case I checked that the equivalence with this description is the essence of proposition$~$5.6 in [this paper](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v3i2r15) I wrote.

Then you are interested in fixed points of this operation, the self-dual standard Young tableaux. These are in bijection with standard domino tableaux (possibly leaving the square nearest the origin uncovered), as stated in proposition$~$2.3.3 of the same paper. More about domin tableaux can be found in [this other paper](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v7i1r35) of mine. This probably explains much of what you observed; I did not check all the details.