# Compute Schutzenberger involution of a Young tableau without using Jeu de Taquin

Tags: combinatorics, young-tableaux

How does one compute Schutezenberger involution $T'$ of a Young tableau $T$ without using Jeu de Taquin.
Can we use Viennot's construction or some other technique and apply it on the contents of $T$ to get $T'$.
I have very limited knowledge about these objects. Any help is most welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Search for “growth diagrams”.

Comment: Words growth and diagram are too common. Can you please elaborate on what you are referring to and why you think that might be useful. Thanks

Comment: If you search google with “growth diagrams schutzenberger involution”, you’ll find a bunch of papers explaining how to compute the involution using growth diagrams. It also turns up in Stanley’s *Enumerative Combinatorics II* somewhere.

Comment: Does the technique in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2067341/a-standard-young-tableau-symmetry-and-the-non-attacking-rook-problem answer your problem? It might.

Comment: remark that you can use the RSK algorithm to rectify the skew tableau obtained above: concatenate the reversed rows of the skew tableau (bottom to up, left to right) to get a permutation, its insertion tableau being the Schutzenberger dual you asked for.

Comment: A Young tableau $Y$ and its corresponding Schutzenberger's operation tableau $T$ can have different sets of integers. So I am not sure what you are referring to, because the operation that you are mentioning seems to have the exact same set of integers in $Y$ and $T$.

Comment: @Vk1: can you give an example of that? I refer to R. P. Stanley, Enum.Comb. Vol 2, ch 7 App 1 (pg 426) proposition A1.2.9

Comment: Thanks for the reference my dear friend. I believe that most inputs which does not have consecutive integers would do the job.
Say the input string is 4,5,1,6. Its YT would have the following structure.
First row would be 1,5,6 and second row would have 4.
The counterpart after performing evacuation would be a YT with first row having 1,2,3 and second row having 6.
Its counterpart YT produced after performing evacuation would have the following rows.

Comment: @Vk1: aha, you want to define the Schutzenberger involution for a semi-standard Young tableau? Is that even well-defined? Remark that for a Standard YT the maximal entry is given, say 'n', and we need the 'complement' of the reading word 'w', so n+1-w as entry to the RSK algorithm. Do you agree?

Comment: Although wiki is not a reliable source to refer, but I am assuming that this part is most probably true. 
The wiki link does mention generalization to semi-standard Young tableaus.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeu_de_taquin
Are you suggesting that we replace every integer $i$ in the word $w$ with $n+1-i$ and they apply standard schensted insertion and that should work as intended to find the evacuation process defined by Schutzenberger?

Comment: @Vk1: I read that as: "jeu-de-taquin" can be generalised to SSYT, but that does not necessarily mean that this leads to an involution on SSYT, like it does for Standard YT. And in your remark above, what value of 'n' would you choose? I mean, {1,1,1},{2,2} is one of the 15 tableaux of shape 3,2 and max element 3, yet its max element is here only 2. So, the definition would need an extra 'size' input here.

Comment: I would choose $n$ to be the maximum element. So the element with value $i$ would be replaced with $n+1-i$. The appendix you mentioned I believe resolves my query. Based on all the various random inputs I tried, it does seem to work perfectly well. Thanks.

Comment: @Vk1: a few counter-examples: {{2, 3, 4}, {3, 4}, {4}}, {{2, 3, 3}, {3, 4}, {4}}, {{2, 2, 4}, {3, 
  4}, {4}}, {{2, 2, 4}, {3, 3}, {4}}, {{2, 2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4}}, {{2, 2, 3}, {3, 3}, {4}}, {{2, 2, 2}, {3, 4}, {4}}, {{2, 2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4}}, all from the set of SSYT of shape 3,2,1 and max element less or equal to 4. So, it's not always an involution. Do you agree?

Comment: Apologies for the error. Let me clarify. If an integer sequence $P$ has maximum element $n$, then I would construct $P_1$ which would be the reverse of $P$ and then,  every element (say $i$) in $P_1$ would be replaced with $n+1-i$ to get $P_2$. The claim as per the source you had referred, implies that the insertion tableau of $P_2$ is the evacuation tableau of $P$.